# How to detect answered or rejected state in outgoing call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

i try to write a program for android .I want to make a call with my program and after that recognize the call status. With Flowing Function I can recognize the hang out status and for answering status it doesn’t work.I try this function but it doesn’t work either

```
private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended, need detect flag
            // from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

            if (isPhoneCalling) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check out the [FAQ] and [About] pages for information on how best to ask questions. In this instance you need to be specific about "doesn't work" - error messages/what does/doesn't happen etc etc.

Answer (score -2):

You can not do that with CALL_STATE_IDLE and CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK.
You have to detect programatically the end of outgoing ringtone...

Comment: Thanks a lot . how can  i do this?